# Check if string is made up from a repeating pattern

Tags: regex, string, perl

I wanted to check if a similar kind of pattern keeps repeating in a binary string.

For e.g. If the string is

```
11110111101111011110 or
100111100111100111100111
```

I want to detect that the first string has 11110 being repeated always and the other has 100111 .
How can I accomplish such task in Perl? The string which is repeating can be of any length.

Comment: what do you mean by first string? First 5 charcaters?

Comment: Can you please reformulate your question?

Comment: @JLILIAman The need is to verify if you can split a "binary" string in several identical sub-strings

Comment: if you need a scalable solution for arbitrarily long strings, maybe look into using a suffix tree. But if your genuine strings are this short, brute force should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is that what you want:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my $re = qr~^(.+?)\1+$~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    say /$re/ ? "OK contains only $1 : $_" : "KO : $_";
}

__DATA__
11110111101111011110
100111100111100111100111
00011110111101111011110
000100111100111100111100111
```

**Output:**

```
OK contains only 11110 : 11110111101111011110
OK contains only 100111 : 100111100111100111100111
KO : 00011110111101111011110
KO : 000100111100111100111100111
```

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of string
(       : capture in group 1
  .+    : any character at least one
    ?   : but as less as possible
)       : end of group 1
\1+     : repeat group 1 at least once
$       : end of string
```

In your first example `11110111101111011110` the regex try to find the shortest substring that is repeated until the end of the string.
It begins with the first character and keep `1` in group 1 then looks if this char is repeated untils the end of the string. It is not, so it tries with the first two characters and so on until if finds a substring that is repeated until the end: it is the substring `11110`.

Comment: How can I also know the number of times the string in $1 has been repeated? This is needed for further improvement.

Comment: @KaranMehta: You have to divide the length of the string by the length of group 1: `length($str) / length($1)`

Answer (score 6):

Use a regular expression:

```
for my $string (qw(11110111101111011110 100111100111100111100111 1101101101)) {
    print $string, ' ', $string =~ /^ (.*?) \1+ $/x ? 'yes' : 'no', "\n";
}
```

Note that it works for any string, not only the ones containing 0's and 1's.

Explanation:

```
^     Beginning of the string.
(.*?) Anything, try from the shortest possible, remember.
\1+   The remembered thing repeated at least once.
$     End of the string.
```

Comment: Can you please provide me a short example and a little detailed explanation Sir?

Answer (score 0):

You would use a regular expression which requires an arbitrary number of repetitions of the given pattern *anchored* at the beginning and the end of the string (using `^` and `$` markers, respectively).  For instance, your example might be written as

```
$count++ if ( $string =~ /^((11110)|(100111))+$/ );
```

to increment a counter.